# How can my Node.js server return data to an exe app after a request

Tags: node.js, json

I'm actually working with Node.js, and I need send data to an exe app not more to the browser and I wanted to please know how I could proceed.

The thing should actually work like. The exe app sends a request (like "http://localhost/users" with GET method) and I need to send the "users" to the app, not to the browser.

Comment: Why not respond to that GET `/users` with the users?

Comment: @ValentinRoudge, this is just an example, but still i could return the data on the browser, or even on the command prompt, but i don't know how I coul send it to the exe program. I wanted to send back data to the program in JSON format